# MUI styled a Custom React Component from external lib does not work

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I currently have a React component that is from a module (it is in node_modules folder):

```
type Props = {
  someProps: any
};

export function ComponentA(props: Props) {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState("");

  return (
    <TextField
      name="search-bar"
      value={value}
      label="Search"
    />
  );
}
```

Then in my project, I want to styled in using styled from mui material and using theme:

```
import {ComponentA} from '..';

export const StyledComponent = styled(ComponentA)(({ theme }) => ({
  width: 'auto',
  height: '5%',
  margin: '10px 15px 20px',
}));
```

Then finally use it like this:

```
<StyledComponent props={someProps: 1}/>
```

This however does not seem to work. Other styled components that were created in my project alone is working correctly. I wonder if I did it wrongly or missing something.

Comment: Pass the className prop in your component, see docs

Comment: styled injects a className. If the component does not accept className you can not style it like this. You may need a wrapper to set the className and style its children.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it with `className` props passed in component, as suggested in the comments.